# dynamic dropdown in rails based on string select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a drop down menu:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">Degree Type:</label>
  <%= f.select(:degreetype, options_for_select([['Bachelor Degree'],['Masters Degree'],['PHD']]),{}, {class:"form-control"})%>
</div>
```

Based on the selection above I want the different dropdown

```
#if Bachelor Degree selected
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">level:</label>
  <%= f.select(:level, options_for_select([['1st'],['2.1'],['2.2'],['3rd']]),{}, {class:"form-control"})%>
</div>

#if Master Degree selected
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="usr">level:</label>
  <%= f.select(:level, options_for_select([['1st'],['2.1'],['2.2'],['3rd']]),{}, {class:"form-control"})%>
</div>
```

`:degreetype` is a string datatype.

Comment: Are these menu's on the same page? I'm assuming that they are and if that's the case I think that this might be better suited to JavaScript. Maybe i'm not fully understanding the question.

Comment: Yes, this requires a simple piece of JavaScript/CoffeeScript.

Comment: you are trying to do like a chain select?